# Why occur KotlinNullPointerException in this code?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a chat app.
When I send the message, it is storaged in firebase real-time database and will be display users with whom i have messages.

but, in this process, occur the KotlinNullPointerExcpetion.

You can read below codes.

First, codes when I send the message. (MessageActivity.kt)

```
sendBtn.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener{
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            var msg = msgSendBox.text.toString()
            if(!msg.equals("")) {
                sendMessage(firebaseUser.uid, receiverId, msgSendBox.text.toString())
                msgSendBox.setText("")
            }
        }
    })
```

.
.

```
private fun sendMessage(sender : String, receiver : String, message : String){
    var reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()

    var hashMap : HashMap<String, Object> = HashMap();
    hashMap.put("sender", sender as Object)
    hashMap.put("receiver", receiver as Object)
    hashMap.put("message", message as Object)

    reference.child("Chats").push().setValue(hashMap)
}
```

and codes that display all users.(UserListFragment.kt)

```
private fun readUsers(){
    var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    var reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")

    reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapShot: DataSnapshot) {

            for(snapShot in dataSnapShot.children){
                var user = snapShot.getValue(User::class.java)

                assert(user != null)
                assert(firebaseUser != null)
                if(!(user?.id.equals(firebaseUser?.uid))){
                    mUsers.add(user!!)
                }
            }

            userAdapter = UserAdapter(context!!, mUsers)

            recyclerView.adapter = userAdapter
        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }
    })
}
```

and codes that display users whom i have messages(ChatListFragment.kt)

```
private fun readChat(){
    mUsers = ArrayList()

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")

    reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapShot: DataSnapshot) {
            mUsers.clear()

            for(snapShot in dataSnapShot.children){
                var user = snapShot.getValue(User::class.java) as User

                for(mId in usersList) {
                    assert(user != null)
                    if (user.id.equals(mId)) {
                        mUsers.add(user)
                    }
                }

            }
            userAdapter = UserAdapter(context!!, mUsers)
            recyclerView.adapter = userAdapter
        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }
    })
}
```

in this codes, it occurs the errors like below.

```
    Process: com.techtown.breadchatapp, PID: 7773
kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
    at com.techtown.breadchatapp.fragment.UserListFragment$readUsers$1.onDataChange(UserListFragment.kt:65)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7506)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:956)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment if its not `mUsers` then it will be your context. You are using the `!!` operator which if `context` is null it will throw the KotlinNullPointerExcpetion

Comment: I tried to remove !! operator but result is same. If so, is it means that context is null?

Comment: I modified context in ChatListFragment.kt, it works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code mentioned in the error:

```
    at com.techtown.breadchatapp.fragment.UserListFragment$readUsers$1.onDataChange(UserListFragment.kt:65)
```

65th line...

Comment: Yes I know.. 65 line code is userAdapter = UserAdapter(context!!, mUsers) but, I tried to debug mUsers and it was not null..

Comment: Check [context!!] it's the source of the exception.